# How to modify observable stream by another observable in RXJS? Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I want to change nested flag in my `ships$` when flag `areShipsExpanded$` will change.
How can I do this. This is what I have so far:

```
areShipsExpanded$: Observable<boolean>;
ships$: Observable<Ship>;

constructor() {
   this.ships$ = this.shipsDataSource.getData().pipe(shareReplay());
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.areShipsExpanded$.pipe(
        map(flag => {
            if (flag) {
                this.ships$.pipe(map(s => s.items.forEach(r => r.isExpanded = flag)));
            }
        })
    ).subscribe();
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that ships$ isn't modified, or maybe I should somehow refresh this `ships$` observable since I'm using it on my view in that way: `<ng-container *ngFor="let ship of (ships$ | async)?.items">`

---

@EDIT

I did it in that way, is it correct, or is the bad practice?

```
this.areShipsExpanded$.pipe(
    map(flag => {
        if (flag) {
            this.ships$ = this.ships$.pipe(map(s => {
                s.items.forEach(r => r.isExpanded = flag);
                return s;
            }));
        }
    })
).subscribe();
```

---

@EDIT2

I used `combineLatest`, should be fine now?

```
shipsData$: Observable<Ship>;
ships$: Observable<Ship>;

constructor() {
   this.shipsData$ = this.shipsDataSource.getData().pipe(shareReplay());
}

this.ships$ = combineLatest(this.areShipsExpanded$, this.shipsData$).pipe
    map(([shipsExpanded, ships]) => {
        ships.items.forEach(r => r.isExpanded = shipsExpanded);
        return ships;
    }),
    share()
);
```

But problem of `combineLatest` that at the beginning functions will be runned 2 times since, both observables emits values. Is there any alternative operator that behaves like `combineLatest` - so when any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each but **ONLY WHEN all observables will be ready**. To avoid repeating at the beginning.

Comment: **On expansion**, you would like to **update** your ships ? Your model doesn't seem to handle that. You should have one Observable and a list of ships. Here, you have two observables. This means that you can only update your ships when your list of ships is changed.

Comment: Search for combining streams in RxJS, you can combine `areShipsExpanded` and `ships` and listen to changes in both and then map the results to create your final `ship$`. Which combination operator to be used depends on your requirement, look for `combineLatest`, `zip` etc.

Comment: @sabithpocker check EDIT please

Comment: does areShipsExpanded has initial value?

Comment: What you did in your edit is that you're overrding `this.ships$` property but the subscribers to the original `this.ships$` will stay subscribed to the original `this.ships$` and not the new one.

Comment: @martin so why it works? :D

Comment: Anyway check my next EDIT

Comment: maybe this.areShipsExpanded$.pipe(withLatestFrom(this.shipsData$),map(//...),share()) cloud help you (stream will only be trigger when this.areShipsExpanded$ is emitting and if this.shipsData$ has emitted a value)

Comment: @OXMO456 But how can I emit `this.areShipsExpanded$` first value when I load this component? Because now values are emitting by button.

Comment: @DiPix look at my answer, maybe this could hep you

Answer (score 0):

May this could help you:

```
const fetchData$ = this.shipsDataSource.getData().pipe(shareReplay());

this.ships$ = merge(
    this.areShipsExpanded$.pipe(
        withLatestFrom(fetchData$),
        map(([shipsExpanded, ships]) => 
            // we could try to favor immutability
            ships.items.map(r => {...r, isExpanded:shipsExpanded})), 
    ), // ships after update
    fetchData$ // initial ships
).pipe(share());
```